# How is oscillation of EM waves determined in cases that don't involve accelerating charges in a/c currents

Tags: electromagnetism

If the frequency of an electromagnetic wave equals the frequency of oscillation of the (source) charge producing it, what about in the case where the accelerating source charge is not oscillating (changing direction) but, instead, is moving in only one direction? After all, the source charge is still accelerating if it's changing speed (for example, EMR emitted when electrons fall to lower energy levels).

Answer (score 1):

You can still decompose its movement in a Fourier transform. The resulting spectrum equals the frequencies emitted.

Comment: @ 1524841: Yes, but an oscillating EM field is produced by an oscillating charge. The back and forth movement of the source charge causes a back and forth movement of the EM field (which propagates outward through this field as EMR). In the case of a source charge that is not oscillating but still accelerating (in one direction), what is causing the back and forth movement of the EM field (producing EMR)? Although we can equate mathematically via Fourier transform the amount of energy in terms of wavelength and frequency, this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, any function may be decomposed into periodic sinusoids via [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis). What we observe in nature corresponds to this math. A prism will separate light into colors representing the Fourier components of the light. Via the [Planck relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_relation), the Fourier power predicts the probability of observing a photon with a given energy. There are many other examples.

Comment: @Rob EMR is due to accelerating charge. Sinusoidal oscillation is a convenient form of acceleration to analyze, and the phenomena are often frequency-dependent, so we generally treat that as elementary. Any acceleration may be decomposed into sinusoidal oscillations via a Fourier transform, and the result of a radiation calculation may then be synthesized via an inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @ John Dity: Yes, but an oscillating EM field is produced by an oscillating charge. The back and forth movement of the source charge causes a back and forth movement of the EM field (which propagates outward through this field as EMR). In the case of a source charge that is not oscillating but still accelerating (in one direction), what is causing the back and forth movement of the EM field (producing EMR)? Although we can equate mathematically via Fourier transform the amount of energy in terms of wavelength and frequency, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Rob You don't need back and forth motion. Acceleration puts a "kink" in the electric field from a charge, and that kink propagates away at the speed of light. That's radiation.

Comment: @ John Doty: Your reply seems to be suggesting that oscillation of the EM field does not actually occur but is, instead, a "convenient" way to analyze EMR mathematically. Wherefore, in the case of non oscillating source charges, we don't require the concept of oscillating EM fields to produce EMR. But then, you're also suggesting that it is actually unknown how precisely EMR IS produced from an accelerating charge (whether vector or scalar).

Comment: @Rob https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential

Comment: @Rob https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system

Comment: @ John Doty: Also, if you're correct, then why is the frequency of EM oscillation equal to the frequency of an oscillating charge and, yet, there is no correlation in frequencies between a non oscillating charge (which can't have frequency) and a mathematically determined frequency of EMR? There is lacking any symmetry between the two scenarios, which is unsatisfying. The first scenario is intuitive, logical and the second scenario,  nebulous, a mystery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140754/discussion-between-john-doty-and-rob).

Answer (score 0):

There are three phenomena you mention and I start from the end of the list: EM radiation from excited electrons, EM radiation from electrons in a circular motion and EM waves from oscillating electrons.

An **electron excited** in the atom emits photons. It is important to emphasize that the understanding of EM radiation as an emission of quanta found by Planck and Einstein is a fundamental one. All EM radiation consists of these corpuscles.

**Deflected electrons** also emit electrons. The only condition is that they have a kinetic energy, because this energy is transformed into EM radiation. The deflection can be a circular motion forced by a coil or by an external magnet. Here is still important the understanding that the (forced, and otherwise this movement also does not exist) circular movement for the electrons represent an acceleration, because every circular movement is an acceleration.

The **synchronous and oscillatory acceleration of surface electrons** in a conductor represents a special case of the emission of photons. The emitted photons have their peak at the times of the largest acceleration values and a zero value at the time with zero acceleration. Perhaps it is worth mentioning that the photons emitted in this way are polarized, i.e. their electric field components are all aligned parallel to the conductor (with changing sign depending on the direction of acceleration). Thus, kinetic energy is also converted into radiation here.

So, as you can see, the emission of excited electrons in the atom is the process that is not associated with acceleration. It is a process in which absorbed photons lead to the raising of the energy level and photons are emitted again at the relaxation.

Comment: @ HolgefFiedler : Doesn't EM radiation mean the same thing as propagating EM waves through the surrounding field produced by a charge? If so, then how do accelerating charges that do not change direction, i.e., which are not deflected or oscillating (such as excited electrons in your example) produce EM waves? For example, in oscillating charges, the frequency/wavelength of EM waves equals that of the oscillating charges. But where accelerated excited electrons aren't changing direction (nothing periodic or oscillating), how do they still produce EM waves?

Comment: Perhaps as to excited electrons (non oscillating accelerating charges), photons are emitted at certain frequencies (and corresponding wavelengths) based on the amount of absorbed energy released. In the case of oscillating accelerating charges (induced by an a/c current for example), photons are emitted at the moment of change in direction in the oscillation, which also translates to a frequency equal to the energy (frequency) of the inducing charge's oscillation (a/c current). So, in both cases, the release of protons is periodic (sinusoidal), resulting in EMR of corresponding frequencies.